# What is the solution of the following definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I encountered this integral in my calculations (picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0qdh.png)):

$$
\int_{f=0}^{f=\pi/2} \frac
{\left(n_0 \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{n_0}{n_1} \sin f \right)^2} - n_1 \cos f\right)^2}
{\left(n_0 \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{n_0}{n_1} \sin f \right)^2} + n_1 \cos f\right)^2}
 2 ~ \sin f ~ \cos f ~\mathrm{d}f
$$

Here, $n_0$ and $n_1$ are constants, such that $n_0$<$n_1$. Both constants are real and positive.

I tried to find solution in Table of integrals,series and products and by using Wolfram mathematica, but I have not managed to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the Lambertian reflectance for parallelly polarised light passing from medium 0 to medium 1, so let us introduce $n = \frac{n_1}{n_0} > 1$ and write your integral as
\begin{align}
r_\text{p} (n) &= \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{n^2 \cos(f) - \sqrt{n^2 - \sin^2(f)}}{n^2 \cos(f) + \sqrt{n^2-\sin^2(f)}}\right)^2 2 \sin(f) \cos(f) \, \mathrm{d} f \\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\stackrel{\sin^2(f) = t}{=} \int \limits_0^1 \left(\frac{1 - \frac{n^2 \sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{n^2-t}}}{1 + \frac{n^2 \sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{n^2-t}}}\right)^2 \, \mathrm{d} t \stackrel{\frac{n \sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt{n^2-t}} = u}{=} 2 n^2 (n^2 - 1) \int \limits_0^1 \frac{u (1-nu)^2}{(1+nu)^2(n+u)^2(n-u)^2} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= 2 n^2 (n^2 - 1) \int \limits_0^1 \left[\frac{8 n^3(n^4+1)}{(n^4-1)^3(1+nu)} - \frac{4n^3}{(n^4-1)^2 (1+nu)^2} \right. \\
&\phantom{= 2 n^2 (n^2 - 1) \int \limits_0^1 \left[\vphantom{\frac{8 n^3(n^4+1)}{(n^4-1)^3(1+nu)}}\right.} \left.  - \, \frac{n^2-1}{(n^2+1)^3 (n-u)} + \frac{(n^2-1)^2}{4(n^2+1)^2n(n-u)^2} \right. \\
&\phantom{= 2 n^2 (n^2 - 1) \int \limits_0^1 \left[\vphantom{\frac{8 n^3(n^4+1)}{(n^4-1)^3(1+nu)}}\right.} \!\left. - \, \frac{n^2+1}{(n^2-1)^3(n+u)} - \frac{(n^2+1)^2}{4(n^2-1)^2 n (n+u)^2}\right] \mathrm{d} u \, .
\end{align}
The remaining integrals are elementary and after some simplification we end up with
$$ r_\text{p} (n) = 1 - \frac{4 n^3 (n^2+2n-1)}{(n^2-1)(n^2+1)^2} + \frac{16 n^4 (n^4+1)}{(n^2-1)^2(n^2+1)^3} \ln(n) - \frac{4 n^2 (n^2-1)^2}{(n^2+1)^3} \operatorname{arcoth} (n) \, .$$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/?source=nav) and [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) can we find solution:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{\left(\text{n0} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\text{n0} \sin (f)}{\text{n1}}\right)^2}-\text{n1} \cos (f)\right)^2 2 \sin (f) \cos (f)}{\left(\text{n0} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\text{n0} \sin
   (f)}{\text{n1}}\right)^2}+\text{n1} \cos (f)\right)^2} \, df=\\\frac{\text{n0}^6+\text{n0}^4 \text{n1}^2-4 \text{n0}^3 \text{n1}^3+7 \text{n0}^2 \text{n1}^4+4 \text{n0}
   \text{n1}^5-\text{n1}^6}{(\text{n0}-\text{n1}) (\text{n0}+\text{n1}) \left(\text{n0}^2+\text{n1}^2\right)^2}-\frac{4 \text{n1}^2 \left(\text{n0}^8+6 \text{n0}^4 \text{n1}^4+\text{n1}^8\right) \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{n0}}{\text{n1}}\right)}{(\text{n0}-\text{n1})^2 (\text{n0}+\text{n1})^2 \left(\text{n0}^2+\text{n1}^2\right)^3}+\frac{16 \text{n0}^2 \text{n1}^4 \left(\text{n0}^4+\text{n1}^4\right)
   \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{n1}}{\text{n0}}\right)}{(\text{n0}-\text{n1})^2 (\text{n0}+\text{n1})^2 \left(\text{n0}^2+\text{n1}^2\right)^3}+\frac{8 \text{n0}^2 \text{n1}^4
   \left(\text{n0}^4+\text{n1}^4\right) \log \left(-\frac{\text{n1}^2}{\text{n0}^2}\right)}{(\text{n0}-\text{n1})^2 (\text{n0}+\text{n1})^2 \left(\text{n0}^2+\text{n1}^2\right)^3}$$

Mathematica code:

`HoldForm[Integrate[(n0 Sqrt[1 - (n0/n1*Sin[f])^2] - 
        n1 Cos[f])^2/(n0 Sqrt[1 - (n0/n1*Sin[f])^2] + 
        n1 Cos[f])^2*2 Sin[f] Cos[f], {f, 0, Pi/2}] == (
    n0^6 + n0^4 n1^2 - 4 n0^3 n1^3 + 7 n0^2 n1^4 + 4 n0 n1^5 - 
     n1^6)/((n0 - n1) (n0 + n1) (n0^2 + n1^2)^2) - (
    4 n1^2 (n0^8 + 6 n0^4 n1^4 + n1^8) ArcTanh[n0/
      n1])/((n0 - n1)^2 (n0 + n1)^2 (n0^2 + n1^2)^3) + (
    16 n0^2 n1^4 (n0^4 + n1^4) ArcTanh[n1/
      n0])/((n0 - n1)^2 (n0 + n1)^2 (n0^2 + n1^2)^3) + (
    8 n0^2 n1^4 (n0^4 + n1^4) Log[-(n1^2/n0^2)])/((n0 - n1)^2 (n0 + 
       n1)^2 (n0^2 + n1^2)^3)] // TeXForm`

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Simplify the integrand by rationalising the denominator. Then use the substitution $f=π/2-g.$